# Use of local pac file

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, pac

I need to use a local pac file when the user is on a vpn.
The problem is that I do not understand how I will get the program to read it. From what I've read .net should be able to pick it up on start from the IE settings. The user can access the web using IE but my program does not work when on vpn, so I guess the pac file is not read. I have set the useDefaultWebProxy to true in that test.

When setting the wcf client proxy address to file:///path/file.pac I get an error that it cannot access it and when searching it can only access http:// so I guess this parameter is not going to work for me.

Any ideas on any workaround?